# Wamp server installation issues

Tags: wamp

I am tring to install Apache wamp server and everytime I have the error:

```
php-win.exe
The program can't start because MSVCR110.dll is missing.
```

I have installed Microsoft C++ 2008 Redistributable-x64 9.0.21022.218 but nothing to do. My OS is a Windows 7 Ultimate Sp1.

Comment: Did you try downloading the missing dll?

Comment: No, where can I get it and where to put in?

Comment: See [point 20 in this document](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,134915) there are links in there Or use the secondary WAMPServer repository [here, also contain links to al the possible required MSVC runtimes](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to install the following

- Microsoft Visual C/C++ Redistributable 2008 (VC9),
- Microsoft Visual C/C++ Redistributable 2010 (VC10),
- Microsoft Visual C/C++ Redistributable 2012 (VC11),
- Microsoft Visual C/C++ Redistributable 2013 (VC13),
- Microsoft Visual C/C++ Redistributable 2015 (VC14)

[Mas información aquí](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,138295)